# Ajax send multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, forms

My html code:

```
<form:form name="vcfForm" id="vcfForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../acquaintance/readingContactsFromVcfFile"></form:form>

<input type="file" name="vcfFile" id="vcfFile" form="vcfForm" >
    <button type="button" name="vcfSubmit" id="vcfSubmit" form="vcfForm">Upload</button>
```

My controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/readingContactsFromVcfFile" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ModelMap readContactsFromVcfFile(@RequestParam("vcfFile") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) throws UserServiceException {
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
  *********************code*****************
  modelMap.addAttribute("message", "success");
  return modelMap;
}
```

My jquery code:

```
 $(document).on('click','#vcfSubmit', function() {
                        var vcfData = new FormData(); 
                        vcfData.append('files[]', $('#vcfForm').get(0).files[0]);
                        $.ajax({
                            url : "../acquaintance/readingContactsFromVcfFile?vcfFile="+vcfData,
                            type : "post",
                            cache : false,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success : function(data) {
                            alert(data.message);                                        
                            }
                            });   
                    });
```

My problem is when i click submit button the page will submitted and return message "success" displayed in page.
I want page not refresh when submitting the form or pass file using ajax.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: ok.but did not working..

Comment: You have `<button type="button"`, that won't submit the form. I can't see any code there that could possibly make the form submit or the page refresh.

Comment: yes but nothing called when i click upload button.[ajax call also not working]

Comment: If possible to passing html file using ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html code:

```
<form name="vcfForm" id="vcfForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ></form>
<input type="file" name="vcfFile" id="vcfFile" form="vcfForm" >
    <button type="button" name="vcfSubmit" id="vcfSubmit" form="vcfForm">Upload</button>
```

controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/readingContactsFromVcfFile" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ModelMap readContactsFromVcfFile(@RequestParam(value = "vcfFile") MultipartFile file, HttpSession session) throws UserServiceException {
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    modelMap.addAttribute("message", "message");
    return modelMap;
}
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click','#vcfSubmit',function(){
                         var vcfData = new FormData($('#vcfForm')[0]); 
                          $.ajax({
                                url : "../acquaintance/readingContactsFromVcfFile?vcfFile="+vcfData,
                                type : "post",
                                data : vcfData,
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                cache : false,
                                success : function(data) {
                                }
                            });   
                    });
```

Every thing working fine.